# Помогите установить GTK+ на linux

Tags: linux, gtk+, gtk3

Скачал gtk+-3.22.0 Разархивировал. Устанавливаю по инструкции. `./configure --prefix=/opt/gtk` вот что получается: https://pastebin.com/6SJA0spD. Пробовал доустановить вручную те пакеты, ошибка. Вот ошибка: `Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev : Зависит: libpixman-1-dev (>= 0.17.7) но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.` Дело в том что я на еще не установленную GTK наверх накатил 32x битную версию GTK.

Comment: Почему бы не поставить это через менеджер пакетов?

Comment: @gbg Нет, подождите, а почему не устанавливается по инструкции с офф сайта?

Comment: @gbg Пробовал через менеджер пакетов не удовлетворяющие зависимости.

Comment: если пакет доступен из менеджера, значит он должен устанавливаться без проблем. а не устанавливается он скорее всего потому что вы лично установили конфликтующие пакеты (зависимости с другими версиями). удалите всё от чего он зависит и попробуйте ещё раз.